# Redoing downvote to counter upvote on new user

Tags: discussion, voting, new-users

While reading another question on meta I noticed talk about downvoting a bad question from a new user, noticing an upvote come in, undoing and then redoing the downvote.

Is there any thoughts/policies on undoing and redoing a downvote on a low rep user after an upvote has come in? To me it seems less welcoming than just downvoting in the first place as it appears to be done in order to remove some of the reputation gained from the bad upvote.

Example:

- New user at 1 rep makes a post
- Existing user downvotes post with no rep lost to new user due to them being at one rep
- Another user comes along and upvotes the post giving the new user 6 rep
- Existing user undoes the downvote, reapplies the downvote which lowers the new users rep from 6 to 4 as a result of the reapplied downvote.

Comment: Do you mean that -1 -> +1 results in +5 rep while +1 -> -1 results in +3 rep? This would only be applicable if user is very close to 1 rep. Otherwise order wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @BDL I added an example, let me know if that makes it clear.

Comment: Even if wrong it is as impossible to block as “pity upvotes”. So we just need lo accept the possibility that these things happen on occasion.

Comment: @yivi There is also the possibility of a new feature that causes vote reversal and reapplication within a short set amount of time to revert back to the amount of reputation that it applied before the changes. This would apply to downvotes of new users and upvotes of users who had already hit the rep cap when the upvote was applied. Though that can still be gotten around but would require more work on the person doing the voting.

Comment: @xdtTransform What does that at all have to do with someone undoing and redoing a downvote that gave no rep loss (due to user being at 1 rep) to counter the rep gain from someone else upvoting the post?

Comment: Undo>Redo, happends. Either because you missjudge the edit and the question is still well within close/burn range. We don't have to counter one reputation gain. For the same reason we do not carry previous downvote in order to cripple an user. As an user will have an hard time coming back from double digit downvote.

Comment: @xdtTransform you are correct they are saying but how often does the sequence go, downvote->another user upvotes->undo downvote->redo downvote all without an edit taking place. Also I would question someone that undoes and redoes a downvote after an edit because they didn't take time to fully read the edit before undoing the downvote.

Comment: Downvote are personal you should not consider others votes in order to decide what to do. Be fair in your vote and Don't try to punish or execute "the justice they deserve" yourself.

Comment: _Also I would question someone that undoes and redoes a downvote after an edit because they didn't take time to fully read the edit before undoing the downvote_ That's neither here nor there. You can question all you want, but that behaviour is not problematic. A user feels that made a mistake and wants to correct it? That's fine.

Comment: @yivi Maybe I am misunderstanding what it being said there but I would find it strange to 'correct' a vote before taking time to understand if that correction is needed or not.

Comment: Joe: user A votes, but afterwards feels that they misread the post and should vote on the other direction. Sees that a small edit is possible on the post, so peforms the edit and "corrects" (votes in the other direction) their vote. I read you comment as if this scenario was something you "questioned".

Comment: @yivi Ah, I see where you are coming from. No I was referring to voting again in the same direction as before. I would classify reversing the direction of your vote a different matter altogether and not covered by reapplying a vote with the goal of it impacting rep the second time around when it didn't (for whatever reason) when it was initially cast.

Comment: I guess I did that ^_^ It was a first for me doing this, and I was just curious what would happen. As it turned out I was surprised that this would work (I honestly thought I wouldn't be able to reapply my downvote) Won't do that again (and will remove that info from the previous question, as I already got some random downvotes since asking the question on some other questions)

Comment: This sounds like a bug. I always thought post rep is a straight `( ( uv * points[5, 10, or 15] ) - ( dv * 2 ) )` rather than an ad-hoc deduction/increase based on user's current rep.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That would actually hurt new users that really get downvoted heavily on a bad initial post, since now it's timestamped and they cannot go below 1, it's not such a problem for them (1 upvote can reverse 10 downvote before that)

Comment: @Icepickle I was thinking that it could be isolated on a per-post basis but I am starting to see how that would quickly get complicated and unfair.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the timeline needs to be factored in; that's what's making the difference for 1-rep users here.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I see the error in my thinking but I'll leave my comment up so that other readers don't make the same mistake.

Comment: I mean... i'd rather we somehow fix it such that the reputation loss stays in tact without the downvoter needing to redo their vote. essentially, hidden negative rep.

Comment: @KevinB Then we would have to force the downvoter to come back and re-evaluate their downvote if the question is edited into a meritable state. As it stands, if the question is edited adequately then future visitor upvotes will reflect the question's adequacy. I really think this is a non-issue since the window of opportunity is as negligible as the affect on reputation.

Comment: Definitely a non-issue. It's no different than any other use of changing votes during the window. It can be used to troll, regardless of the rep change, but it's a necessary feature. Negative rep would be bad for new user engagement, and hidden negative rep even more so as it would also be confusing.

Comment: @Goyo Besides the fact that I mentioned this was asked because someone said they did that?

Comment: My bad, I guess I skipped over four characters  while reading your question.

Comment: Just to add to what others have said, negative rep, hidden or not, provides an incentive for the user just to start over with a new account.

Comment: I was thinking about asking this too before, but if that happens, i would un-upvote and up-vote again, back to 6 rep :-)

Comment: I agree with @KevinB, just hide the negative rep until rep gets high enough.

Comment: Can you prove this is happening as a pattern of bad behavior? Can you prove that the user is doing it maliciously in order to harm the poster? If it's a single incident, you're making a fuss over nothing. If you think you've spotted a pattern of misconduct, flag the post for a moderator's attention and report the behavior. I've downvoted a post, noticed the user has edited it, reversed the downvote, and then realized that the edit wasn't really an improvement and downvoted again. It was not to affect the user's rep, but because the question was still poor. Your *fix* would be wrong there.

Comment: @JonathanM - *"I agree with KevinB, just hide the negative rep until rep gets high enough."*  Actually his point was that hidden negative rep is confusing and bad.  (And I agree with that)

Comment: @KenWhite My fix would leave the vote and the reputation impact exactly like it was before you undid and redid your vote so why would it be wrong because it didn't change anything after you cycled a vote on a poor question that was edited?

Comment: @JoeW: Because if the poster made an edit that I initially thought would improve the post and I removed the downvote, the poster then got an upvote, and then I decided to re-apply my downvote, by standards here the poster  *should* have their reputation affected, just like any other poster who has reputation and then receives a downvote.  It interferes with the designed functionality of this site, and the entire process behind voting and reputation. You have what at  this point is an *unproven problem*, and applying a system-wide change to fix a non-existent problem is wrong.

Comment: @KenWhite I understand that but what I am suggesting would return everything to its initial state before you incorrectly removed your downvote. Is it really fair to the poster for them to lose the rep for the downvote because you made a mistake in retracting your downvote when you should not have? The problem here is you made a mistake and someone else is getting impacted by it.

Comment: @JoeW: You're missing the point. Take my scenario (DV, edit, remove DV, realize post is worse). In this case, the DV is appropriate based on the *new* current state of the post, and any rep the poster has at that time *should be* affected. In addition (and for the third time, since it seems that you're ignoring it), before you provide a solution, there must first be proven that there is an actual problem to solve,  and you've not provided any proof that systematic bad behavior is prevalent enough to require a solution. Read my first comment again. Where's the evidence that this is a problem?

Comment: My suggestion: Collect actual evidence that the voting process you've described is a systemic, prevalent problem. Collect actual posts from a large number of users that demonstrates this issue, including links to the posts. Pass them on to the SO team or a moderator to investigate, once you've collected that actual evidence. At that point, when there is a proven issue, a system-wide change may be needed. You've not provided any evidence of an issue at all yet.

Comment: @KenWhite On the flip side would it not be a more rational decision to take some time and consideration to fully review the post before voting or changing a vote to ensure you are taking the correct action on the post. As for the evidence that is the purpose of this discussion post to gather other peoples thoughts on it.

Comment: @StephenC, I think KevinB was in favor of it, as he followed up with: "I mean... i'd rather we somehow fix it such that the reputation loss stays in tact without the downvoter needing to redo their vote. essentially, hidden negative rep. ". I think it's a good idea that negative rep gets applied when the user gets a high enough rep to keep their rep total above a certain threshold.

Comment: @JonathanM - He also said "Negative rep would be bad for new user engagement, and hidden negative rep even more so as it would also be confusing."  - You can't possibly construe that as meaning he thinks negative rep is a good idea.

Comment: @StephenC, mebbe. I'll let Kevin speak for himself. It makes sense to me that when a negative vote given, it should be reflected once the user has enough rep to show it. If you see differently, that's ok. This isn't a big issue.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Votes (up, down, close, delete, etc.) have nothing to do with being welcoming.  They are curation, which we use to maintain our quality standards.  All posts must meet those standards, new users and established users alike.

That said, re-voting on a post because of what someone else has done isn't really a good idea.  They're primarily supposed to send a signal to future readers, which it does no matter what order the votes come in.  Doing it specifically to counteract a rep gain is getting awful close to voting on the user.

Vote on the post.  Who votes on it afterwards is immaterial to the primary goal.

Comment: I was referring more to the act of undoing and redoing the vote in order to cause reputation loss than the vote itself since in cases like this it would have caused no reputation lost when first cast.

Comment: `Doing it specifically to counteract a rep gain is getting awful close to voting on the user.`  And the last paragraph is what we're trying to do.  Send that signal; that's more important than reducing someone's rep by two points.

Comment: Which is why I asked the question.

Comment: I would undo my action (it was indeed against the post and not against the user) if I could, but that post has been deleted already anyhow...

Comment: @Icepickle As long as you're voting on the post, no issue.  The scenario being presented is specifically voting because someone else voted in a manner you didn't like.

Comment: I dunno, I'm kind of on both minds here.  Voting against the user is more along the lines of voting *because* of the user.  In this context, the OP is already voting on the question.  Someone *else* comes in and votes *because* of the user (e.g. upvote to "cancel out" the downvote).  It's likely not the way votes were intended to be used, but it's also not really voting fraud since again, the OP was already voting on the question.

Comment: @Makoto Voting specifically to cause a reputation reduction, *after* you've already voted on it previously, seems kinda sketchy to me.  Someone else giving a pity upvote doesn't mean you should respond in kind.  Two wrongs don't make a right.

Comment: @fbueckert:  I don't disagree, which is why I'm of both minds here.   If it were the case that this happened in the other sequence, we wouldn't be here.  It's also very likely the case that this happened in the cool-down period of a vote, where the voter has an opportunity to change their mind.  Voting on the user isn't good, but then we're now restricting the voter's ability to undo/redo their vote.

Comment: @Makoto I'm definitely not saying any action is required here; definitely don't restrict voting in any sense.  Just that some additional perspective is in order.

Comment: Makoto, My thoughts are not to restrict anything with voting but making it so that when you undo and redo the vote in a short period of time it has the same reputation impact as before you undid and redid it.

Comment: @JoeW I agree, that would be a good solution and already works the other way round (downvoting a 1 rep user and undoing it does not re-add the score that were not initially subtracted)

Comment: @Makoto, fbueckert: I think those are voting against a user, but against the upvoting user, not the author of the question. I agree we shouldn't allow this. However, we have all seen questions at -7 receiving an upvote from someone feeling hostile against the moderating users, yielding the net effect of +5. And that hurts. It feels like they are working against quality control.

Comment: To a degree, I'd agree, @Patrick.  I know I'm annoyed when I see an obviously bad question upvoted.  Especially when you notice a pattern that points to someone actively working against quality.  But...re-voting on the question has no effect for the upvoter; all it does is cause a rep loss for the poster.  That's why I feel it's more of a focus on the poster.  I take solace in the fact that the crappy question will shortly be deleted, and take the pity upvotes with it.

Comment: Voter intent aside, isn't an easy solution to have SO automatically re-tally rep points from previous votes once a user's points get above a certain threshold?

Comment: @fbueckert I totally agree. IMHO, this is the actual issue that needs to be solved. Not the re-voting thing.

Comment: Not sure I follow, @Patrick.  The issue is the pity upvoting?

Comment: @fbueckert Sorry I was unclear. The problem seems to be that people don't see what we are actually doing here, and think they need to revenge vote, shout at us for closing, answering off-topic questions, etc.

Comment: @Patrick I am totally on board with setting those expectations up front.  It has to happen there, before someone asks their first question, so they're aware of what we expect, and how they can meet them.  Unfortunately, the messaging we've been getting has been extremely lopsided in regards to that, so I'm not at all confident we'll ever reach a point where users will understand the system decently prior to their first question.  I lament the days where users would try to acclimate to new environments before participating in them.

Answer (score 23):

No, you shouldn't do this. If nothing else, it's a waste of your time. Who cares enough about a 2-rep impact on another user to bother playing these games?

However, you can never be sure that you have observed this. Somebody who retracts a vote and then reapplies it may simply have changed their mind, or misclicked the first time they voted. We can't possibly stop or punish it, because we can't identify it in the first place without first developing the ability to read users' minds through via the internet.

Comment: The question isn't about observing it happening but rather a result of someone saying that they have done this.

Comment: @JoeW Ah - the question didn't explicitly say that and I assumed it not to be the case. Anyway, that seems very much like an edge case; I doubt you'll ever see anyone admit to that conduct again.

Comment: If you downvote > leave the page > come back (I use the 2 side buttons on my mouse for this) > and then check the score again, nothing changed which results in people tapping the downvote button again thinking they did not vote. This could also be a potential case

Comment: @Tomm Indeed. Or maybe the voter clicked the button lots of times because they enjoy seeing it change color. Humans are difficult-to-understand creatures with diverse minds and motivations; when you force a large set of humans into each picking one option from a small set of possible actions, you can bet they'll make their choices based on every motivating factor you could think of and then a bunch more besides.

Comment: Very well said, could not have done it better.

Answer (score -6):

Just because you think a post is worthy of a downvote doesn't mean that everyone else will agree with you.

Undoing your downvote and then re-downvoting specifically to make the new user lose reputation accomplishes no real goal. Leave the question for other users to decide whether it is an appropriate question for the site. If others on the site agree with you that its a bad question then the user will lose that reputation eventually anyways.

This is a community-driven site and you are trying to abuse the downvote system on users with 1 reputation (when asking the question) to push your own judgement of their question ahead of what the community in general believes. Whether its a pity upvote or not- you shouldn't be strategically voting on questions assuming such things. Downvote and move on- don't downvote and stalk the question making sure the new user gains as little rep as possible because you think its a bad question.

Comment: How exactly is it "abuse"? The most rep you as an individual can actually affect on an individual user on a single question is -2 rep.

Comment: I would think this is similar to someone downvoting competing answers where is is not abuse of the system but not something to be encouraged.

Comment: @Makoto Are you saying the system was intentionally designed for high rep users to sit and wait on a question and strategically downvote/redownvote to make sure a new user loses rep? If not- its misusing/abusing the downvote system

Comment: @Makoto but rep is never negative, so if you're a new user with 1 rep, get 1 downvote, then that downvote had 0 effect on your rep. Then you get +1, and now you stand at +5 (unless I'm missing something). Undoing the previous downvote and re-applying it again after the new user earned enough rep to lose any, will bring it to +3. It's "abusive" in the sense that it's leveraging a 5-minute window (assuming no edits to the OP) to turn a no-rep-effect downvote into one that counts for -2, effectively voting twice.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon:  Your vote only *ever* counts once.  If you undo your vote, then your vote doesn't count by any metric.  This is true even if you've cast a vote on a question ten years ago, and you went back and undid it.

Comment: @chevybow:  I do want to respond to your concerns but I feel like your statement is a bit too laced with some kind of bias or resentment.

Comment: @Makoto your downvote on a 1-rep user has no effect. Scores are tallied according to the voting timestamp. If you remove your no-op vote while you're allowed to do so (within 5 minutes), and then later vote down again after the user earned some rep from someone else's upvote, then your 2nd vote now shaves 2 rep off the OP's tiny little reputation score, i.e. you voted twice.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon:  I'm going to respond to your point about the five-minute window, since that's what I want to take into account here. Suppose then a user decides to "reconsider" their vote based on peer pressure (yes, this is a thing that can happen with voting score).  If they undo their vote and then decide that "no, really, this question *is* bad", then they would be well within their rights to re-cast their downvote.  At that point, can you objectively say that they're voting on the user or on the post?  The devil is in the details on this one.

Comment: @Makoto I don't see how my statement has any sort of bias on it. I am responding to the very specific situation outlined in the OP where a user downvotes a question which results in no rep loss- revisits the question and chooses to cancel their vote and immediately re-downvote when they see that the user now has reputation gained from the question. I am under the assumption that the site did not intend users to act this way- yes- but if you think my assumption is incorrect you are always welcome to try and change my mind.

Comment: @Makoto not sure what you think I'm saying or what you're arguing about. I'm thinking we're both saying the same thing (this vote-undo-revote behavior *is* toxic behavior, very much targeting a new user's low rep score), as is chevybow's answer. Hence I don't understand the pile-on downvotes on this answer that we all seem to be agreeing with.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon:  I'm not saying that it's toxic.  That's a ***very*** strong projection of someone's intent with their voting.  For every person who *might* do this just because they want to be sure a user doesn't get rep, there *might* be others who don't - who genuinely feel like they should reconsider and then upon reconsidering, decide that, after all, the question *should* be downvoted.

Comment: @Makoto fine, benefit of the doubt. From the standpoint of the new user though, it's extremely hard to grant that benefit of the doubt if they've just read 12 Twitter threads and 3 blog posts about how hard it is to post on SO and how it's completely filled with no-lifers that get high on sprinkling downvotes and closing questions. I once put up a thread about how to ask a good on-topic question on SO and got quote-tweeted with "this is everything that's wrong in tech" - if something can be construed as "toxic", it will. I'm just saying maybe we can *try* to avoid doing that, for our own sake.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon There are always going to be users who don't care at all about our quality standards.  There's no reason to cater to their perception in any sense.  Not performing curation for fear of being labelled, "toxic" or, "unwelcoming" just does the site a disserve; it's not like we're going to be changing their opinions of the site.  I think it's better to focus on ensuring the site is a good repository of knowledge.  People will continue to use it, even if they label it toxic.

Comment: @fbueckert the whole point is that if you've already downvoted, then you've already done the "curation" part. Re-doing your downvote just to make sure the new user gets slapped with that -2 is just plain bloody wrong, as your own answer (which I agree with) states.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes, I have no issue with that.  But Makoto has a very valid point; as long as you're voting *on the post*, there's nothing wrong with undownvoting, and, upon reconsideration, redownvoting.  I've done that multiple times on posts, especially after edits.  Doing it during the initial voting window, though, is wrong.  A user getting -2 from someone who previously voted, though, isn't automatically wrong.

Comment: I'm thinking the fix is to leave the voting userID in the timeline rather than nuking the vote record; that way re-downvoting would keep your new downvote in the same place timeline-wise as your original vote, and re-voting truly would have no effect whatsoever, and everybody would be happy, except the downvoter that actually meant that re-vote to hurt the user's rep score and standing rather than that post's overall score.

Comment: *...you are trying to...* This part makes it seem like you think the OP was doing this or suggesting doing this but this was something the OP thinks they saw, not something they agree with.

Comment: if this was the other way (someone who is at the 200 rep a day limit, gets upvoted, then I undo my upvote to redo it after they got downvoted and aren't close to the limit anymore), will this be labeled as "Abuse" in the same way? and "toxic" in the same way? Cause.... it's the same behavior after all....

Comment: @Patrice yes, it would. It's no less *targeted*.

Comment: @Mathieu good! I agree. I just know that a lot of our users are quick to scream at actions like that, but only if it's "negative reception". I just wanted to be sure you had the consistency. I agree if it's done *to* remove rep, it's garbage. Now it's difficult to make a case for "this was the intent" or not.... so that's where I side a bit more with Makoto

Comment: @Patrice hence, leaving the voting userID in the timeline being a reasonable fix: if they meant to downvote the *post*, then no harm done, reinstate the vote, done. If they meant to downvote/punish the *user*, then a re-voting wouldn't be affecting the timeline, and that wouldn't be happening. Same going up or down.

Comment: @Mathieu it depends on how complicated it is to implement (something tells me it'll be a LOT more complex than we thought), but it could fix the issue, I agree.

Comment: Use your time on more important questions

Answer (score -25):

It's too bad the voting process isn't more granular.  If there 3-4 categories available for voting, you could focus on the issues that are more or less important to SO.  If a new poster is getting down voted for failing to provide a good enough example on their first post, they aren't going feel welcomed here, especially since there is no feedback loop on a down vote.  Having a couple of categories to vote on that are available to mods and high rep. users and a couple that are available to the "general public" would allow a more focused feedback on the real issues of the post.

I also think that any down vote should come with a required comment.  I can remember getting down voted on a post and not having a clue what I had done to deserve it.

We should be focused on making SO better and not just scoring each other's posts.

Comment: Curation has nothing to do with being welcoming.  You're conflating two different things.  Your second request is also often requested, and is always rejected.  Votes are not on *you*; they are for the *post*.

Comment: Here's a classic example of what I was talking about.  4 down votes and one comment about why.  If I was a new user and this was my first post, I'd feel like you're a bunch of jerks and would go elsewhere.  Most people are open to constructive criticism, but simply dinging thier post with no feedback is pretty rude, IMO.

Comment: Well, that's that conflation I just told you about.  You've made no attempt to learn how meta works, or done any research into the systems.  The votes are telling you (and, more importantly, future readers) that this post is disagreed with (here on Meta), and on Main, that this post wouldn't be worth reading.  The votes are not for *you*.  It feels awful unwelcome for us, too, to continually get told we're jerks by people who don't understand the system.

Comment: "Most people are open to constructive criticism" I find it a very rare trait.  You, for example, were given constructive criticism, and responded to it unconstructively, right here in this post.  Demanding people give you *even more* feedback, when you're ignoring the feedback you're getting (or worse, attacking those people for giving it) doesn't support your case very well.

Comment: fbuekert, I know what you're saying, but we're looking at this from the inside out.  WE know that voting is about the post, but the new user (and some older users) don't have that perspective.  They see that came to a place with a great rep. for helping people and the first thing that happens is that they get a down vote and have no idea why.  How do you think that makes them feel about SO?

Comment: I don't care how that makes them feel; we're curating the site.  If someone tracks in mud into a museum, and walks right past the, "No muddy shoes" sign, does the janitor care about the person doing the tracking?  No.  You clean it up.  We aren't being jerks about it; we're not insulting you, or attacking you.  In fact, I'm *explaining* to you why you're wrong, and trying to educate you on how things work.  That's the polar opposite of being a jerk.  I'm pointing you at the sign that says not to wear muddy shoes.

Comment: @FrankBall:  While some of your points are already established - you can search Meta for why suggestions on mandatory commenting on downvotes are shot down - I want to share with you that a downvote doesn't just magically appear.  997 times out of 1000, there is a justifiable reason for them.  This curation system is a two-way street; good questions or answers (as we see them) will be upvoted, and bad questions or answers (as we see them) will be downvoted.

Comment: I'm not calling anyone a jerk, I made comment that simply down voting a post with no explanation of why would make a new person think that the people here are jerks.  Curation is not just cleaning up the mud, it's a process of trying to make sure people understand why tracking mud in is wrong.  If all you're doing is sweeping up, then you're helping to perpetuate the problem by not educating people when they do something wrong. I've been a mod on multiple discussion forums and the first thing you do when someone crosses a line is make sure that they understand what it was that they did wrong.

Comment: The problem with that, Frank, is that there thousands, if not *tens* of thousands, more people than there are janitors.  We literally *cannot* tell everyone to read the sign, or educate them personally.  That's why the signs *exist*; so that users can educate themselves without needing someone to sit them down and tell them what they did wrong.  Users *have* to be able to exhibit some modicum of effort on their own behalf; the system can't work without that.  Eventually, those users will get banned without that effort, because we just can't allow them to continually track in mud over and over.

Comment: We need robots to vote

Comment: Nah ... we already have robots in the Review queues.  :-)

Comment: Voting is anonymous for a reason.  It prevents noise and clutter and needless serial (revenge) downvoting. Hover your mouse over the down voting arrow, and read the popup hint, which tells you why the post was worthy of being downvoted. Voting serves a purpose, and all the touchy-feely "Lets make the world feel welcome here" doesn't mean we have to allow low-quality garbage to remain here. If we do, we might as well just close the place down and let one of those other crappy Q&A sites collect the clutter instead.