# Looks like someone is abusing the votes, should I care?

Tags: discussion, upvotes, serial-voting

I'm looking at the newest question and I see quite a few questions in a row all upvoted but some have just 3 views which is very rare to get upvoted within a minute.

And when I look at the actual questions, some I would downvote or ask for more details.

[image]

Is there anything I should do? Or would you say "Mind your own business"?

I'm thinking to myself why don't I ask a question now to get some upvotes :).

Comment: there's protections against this

Comment: Its not really serial voting unless someone is targeting a particular user. You can vote on posts as you see fit based on how you find it useful or not

Comment: People will upvote crap sometimes. It's baffling but it happens.

Comment: If you think a voting pattern is sketchy, flag for moderator attention on a post and explain your concerns (*in detail*, it is important). This situation looks like business as usual, though.

Comment: Is this the opposite question of [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411113/is-there-a-better-course-of-action-for-when-detecting-an-unusual-surge-of-compla)?

Comment: I mean 3 views is (probably) 3 people. Is it so unreasonable to think one of them casts a vote? It is good to be vigilant, but don't go looking for patterns. You'll see them everywhere on this busy busy site of ours.

Comment: @Gimby You're right it might be true that the votes were given by different people, or in good faith. But the interesting thing is that it's all one after the other, and some I would downvote and/or flag. And I should add that same thing I saw yesterday but just couldn't add the image to the question.

Comment: Shmiel, the network as a whole has some established users who want to encourage new users to remain in the community by upvoting their marginal or even bad questions. As long as the votes aren't targeted at specific users, there's nothing specifically against the rules there. Also, such behavior would be exceedingly difficult to detect, because it looks just like normal behavior.

Comment: When I get a bunch of votes in a row that seem to follow a pattern like most or least recent in order or top or lowest voted in order, I'll wait a few days to see if the automated abuse tracker nukes the votes, then report. If I remember, that is. The more bizarre the circumstances, the more likely I'll remember. Anyway, the mods have a full plate of other garbage to dig through, so if a bot can mete out justice, let the bot do the smiting.

Comment: @IanCampbell ".. it looks just like normal behavior." That's what the question here is based on. It looks suspicious because it's upvotes where usually downvotes are warranted. In order to find such anomalies one would kind of calculate some correlation of individual voting behavior vs. general voting behavior and look for negative correlations. But that still might not be a misuse just a different opinion and the company probably does not have the tools for that available.

Comment: `I'm thinking to myself why don't I ask a question now to get some upvotes` Aren't upvotes worthless in meta?

Comment: @TheMaster: That sentence is not talking about this meta question, it's idly / jokingly considering posting a question on main SO to ride that apparent train of free upvotes on every question regardless of quality.

Comment: I think it's possible someone was trying to get the [Vox Populi](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi) badge "Use the maximum 40 votes in a day."

Comment: Maybe there should be an initial `time delay` after question is posted, before being allowed to down/up votes, to check if the content is actually grasped/read/seen. This delay can be based on the number of parapgraph words or code lines or other measurable content. For example: 15 seconds per image, 3 seconds per paragraph line and 7 seconds per code line. Add it all up and there is your initial time delay before anyone can place any vote on anything. The idea is: how could any vote if the content is unread? At least this highers the ramp for alle the instant votes pictured in the question.

Answer (score 7):

Twice I've flagged suspicious upvotes on bad questions, noting that it's unlikely anyone would have upvoted the question in good faith.

The first time (April 30) a moderator marked it "helpful", the second time (Jun 3) "declined", asking me to **only report if I'd noticed a voting *pattern* myself over more than one question**.  I don't know if this was due to changes in moderator workload, or just that the first question was handled by moderator deletion and thus the flag was marked helpful for the wrong reason, not for the voting report.

In your case, it's different people's questions being upvoted by (perhaps) one user, across various tags, so probably not a voting ring or sockpuppet.  Hopefully a moderator will answer this meta question, but they may not have time to look into reports on a string of votes like this which may be innocent.

As commenters pointed out, it's possible someone was just feeling "generous", and voted this way without considering the content of the questions.  That is not the intended purpose of upvotes on Stack Overflow, but it isn't something that moderators police; it won't get a user suspended.  (I still don't recommend upvoting low-quality posts, that defeats the purpose of post score and makes future searches harder to filter.)

---

The first time I flagged, on a total garbage question where I couldn't even tell what they were asking (in the [assembly] tag), a moderator marked it helpful.  The upvote came within minutes of the question being posted, which makes it more suspicious for a relatively low-traffic tag without a huge number of regular users watching it.

(My suspicion was that a sockpuppet account, or a classmate, was upvoting it because of who posted it, not because of the content.  Voting rings, and voting for yourself via another account, are both disallowed on SO.)

> Suspicious upvote: This question is total garbage, and obviously so. Meaningless title, no question asked, no text. I can sometimes guess what an unclear question wants, but there's nothing here. (The code-dump is 32-bit NASM for Linux in the first half, then 16-bit MASM for DOS in the 2nd half. Obviously copy/pasted, and neither half is HLA). Whoever upvoted this might have just thought asm is nifty, but make me wonder if a classmate upvoted this for this person not based at all on quality.
> – Peter Cordes Apr 30 at 7:23
>
> *helpful*

It was [then closed and deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061568/depending-on-the-options-in-effect-high-level-assembler-requires-the-files) by Martijn Pieters♦, so perhaps the "helpful" status was based on the "very low quality" aspect, rather than the voting report.

---

The second time, I flagged a bad question which didn't specify an architecture.  (That makes an assembly question unanswerable; it would be like asking for someone to do your homework for you in "a C-like language", but without specifying whether it was C++, Java, C#, C, Objective-C, or whatever.  Or which set of libraries to use for I/O.)

> possible voting irregularity: most reasonable people wouldn't have upvoted this (1 upvote within an hour of posting). A trivial but totally vague question, no architecture specified. And looks like homework with no attempt.
> – Peter Cordes Jun 3 at 6:37
>
> *declined - A single vote is not enough to draw any conclusions. I see nothing obvious here that would point to secondary accounts. If you find more evidence, please flag it again.*

Not linking this one to protect the guilty, since it's not deleted, only closed as a duplicate of a Q&A for a random architecture.  The querent did later comment with what assembler, but didn't bother to edit their question to improve it in any other way.

Since it was already closed, and could have become a decent question with an attempt, there wasn’t any need for moderator action other than the voting.

Comment: *"IDK if this was due to changes in moderator workload, or just that the first question was handled by mod deletion and thus the flag was marked helpful for the wrong reason, not for the voting report."* The flag was, indeed, marked helpful at the same time as the post was deleted, but I wouldn't assume that was accidental. Mods tend to know how the system works & take advantage of it to save clicks. I'd say it's just different mods handling flags differently. It's true that a single suspicious upvote isn't really actionable, but those flags can be useful to bring other issues to our attention

Comment: I really don't have time to investigate this particular report/concern at the moment, but I honestly doubt *any* mod will be able to answer this question, as our tools just don't work to give us visibility into this. We can easily investigate suspicious voting by/on users, but we have no way to investigate suspicious voting on *posts* (e.g., up/downvoting all posts with a particular tag). That kind of thing requires a staff member to investigate. Mods could escalate to staff and request that be done, if it's something egregious enough to merit the time for all parties involved.

Comment: @CodyGray: I didn't mean truly "accidental", I was guessing that Martijn intentionally chose to handle the flag in a way that would mark it as helpful because the very-low-quality part was helpful, even if the voting part wasn't.  I'd assumed that mods could see who voted on a post, and had other tools to dig further.  The fact that only staff can usefully investigate makes it pretty clear that it's not useful to report one-offs that aren't worth a mod escalating for staff attention.  You might want to say that in an answer, as general guidance about what mods can usefully do.

Comment: I believe sockpuppetting is not disallowed on SO, if used for legitimate reasons.

Comment: @TheMaster: Fair enough, rephrased to just say that voting for yourself via another account is disallowed.

Comment: I am not aware of any legitimate use of sockpuppetting, @TheMaster.

Comment: @CodyGray: Perhaps they mean "having a secondary account".  A very few users do that openly, although the only one I know of is [Ciro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82-%E5%85%AD%E5%9B%9B%E4%BA%8B) [Santilli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9160762/ciro-santilli).  I wouldn't be surprised if others have anonymous accounts, e.g. for workplace.SE questions where they don't want to self-identify, possibly tech Q&As too. But using the term "sockpuppet" to describe it has connotations of being up to no good.

Comment: @CodyGray The [sockpuppet wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/sock-puppets/info), per my understanding,  says otherwise: "*a sockpuppet account can be legitimate, provided you play by the rules.*", "*Note that having more than one account for a legitimate purpose is permitted.*"

Comment: @CodyGray better than the sockpuppet wiki entry, see [this old answer by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/200582). Having multiple accounts is not per se against the rules; *abuse* of multiple accounts (including voting on one's own posts, boosting ones own arguments, or bypassing bans or limits) is against the rules. I've used sockpuppets on other Stack Exchange sites myself in the past when - for one reason or another - having my post attached to my real name might pose a legal risk to me, my employer, or those I care about.